# Why does an activity playing a sound disturb the user interface?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-mediaplayer, android-notifications

I would like to show a notification and play a sound when the user taps onto that notification. It works somehow when I use an activity to play the sound, as I have written in my own answer to this question: [How can I create a notification that plays an audio file when being tapped?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63961419/how-can-i-create-a-notification-that-plays-an-audio-file-when-being-tapped) (in this question and answer there is also the source code showing how I create the notification and how my `PlaySoundActivity` looks like.

Yet, I have realized, that while the sound is playing, the appearance of my main application changes and it will not be restored without closing the application.

I have created my application from the "Tabbed Activity" project template.

This is how it looks after being started:

[image: Application like I expect it to be]

And this is how it looks when I have tapped onto the sound notification (the sections are gone):

[image: "Disturbed" user interface]

Can anyone explain why this happens? Is it a wrong approach to play sound using an activity? But it does not work here when I use a service, I hear nothing! How to solve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Android developer reference, "almost all activities interact with the user, so the Activity class takes care of creating a window for you in which you can place your UI with setContentView(View)".

I had not done this. Therefore a new window was displayed, but there was no content.

The better solution for playing a sound is to use a `PlaySoundService` (service!!!) instead of an activity. It contains almost the same code as an activity would do, but the pending intent is created with `PendingIntent.getService(...)` instead of `PendingIntent.getActivity(...)`. Using the wrong method does not result in an obvious error message, but the service won't work as expected.